# как сохранить состояние ViewPager?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-viewpager

ViewPager с тремя табами. По середине человечек (WaveProgressBar). Этот человечек наполняется жидкостью, когда я нажимаю на кнопку, но когда я переключаюсь на другую вкладку, а потом возвращаюсь обратно к человечку, он сбрасывается и наполняется жидкостью по новой, как сделать чтобы он не сбрасывался?

пробовал использовать `view_pager.setOffscreenPageLimit()` ничего не дало.

ещё интересный момент, в горизонтальной ориентации он не сбрасывается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Переопределите `onSaveInstanceState()` метод:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"fragmentInstanceSaved",getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container));
}
```

И добавьте следующее в `onCreate` метод:

```
if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState,"fragmentInstanceSaved");
        //recreate your preserved fragment here
    }else{
        //goto ur default activity or fragment....
}
```